# Calculation of the integral $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} |ax+by| e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$ where $a,b>0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

So I was given as a hint to change variables to a rotation transformation:
$u=\frac{ax+by}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} , \ v = \frac{ax-by}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.

I computed the Jacobian of this transformation which is: $(a^2+b^2)/(2ab)$.

Thus the integral becomes:
$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} dudv |u|\frac{(a^2+b^2)^{3/2}}{2ab} e^{-\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}[(u+v)^2/(4a^2)+(u-v)^2/(2b^2)]}$$

The argument in the exponent becomes: $$(-(a^2+b^2)/(8a^2 b^2))\cdot [(a^2+b^2)(u^2+v^2)+2(b^2-a^2)uv]$$

I don't see how to simplify matters here, can someone help me with this exercise?

Thnaks!
Perhaps another change of variables is in order, don't know.

Comment: Should be $v = \frac{ax - by}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, and $e^{-\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\left[(u+v)^2/(4a^2) + (u-v)^2/(4b^2)\right]}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the hint has a typo. Indeed, the given change of variables is not a rotation. Instead, you may use the change of variables

$$ u = \frac{ax+by}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}, \qquad v = \frac{-bx+ay}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}. $$

Then the Jacobian is simply $1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = u^2 + v^2$, and so,

$$ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} |ax + by| e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
= \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} |u| e^{-\frac{1}{2}(u^2+v^2)} \, \mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v. $$

The right-hand side can be computed by invoking the Fubini's Theorem to reduce it to an iterated integral.